# Declaring byte array for getting bytes from a file

Tags: c#

Basically I'm reading all the bytes from a file into a byte array using stream reader.

The array I have declared looks like this : `byte[] array = new byte[256];`

The size of the array 256 can read the whole bytes from the file? Saying that a file has 500 bytes instead of 256?

Or the each element from the array has the size 256 bytes?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: What command are you using to read in?  You won't be able to read in > 256 bytes into a 256 byte array.

Comment: I'm using the BaseStream.Read function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) instead:

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

or if you just want to know the size, with a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(path);
long s1 = f.Length;
```

**Edit**: If you want to it "in a classical way" as commented:

```
byte[] array;
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    int num = 0;
    long length = fileStream.Length;
    if (length > 2147483647L)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("File is greater than 2GB, hence it is too large!", "path");
    }
    int i = (int)length;
    array = new byte[i];
    while (i > 0)
    {
        int num2 = fileStream.Read(array, num, i);
        num += num2;
        i -= num2;
    }
}
```

(reflected via `ILSpy`)

Comment: Yes I know but I want to do it in a classical way

Comment: @JoshuaBlack: Added the "classical way" although i would prefer `File.ReadAllBytes` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
 byte[] byteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

and then you can find out how long the file was by looking at the `byteData.Length` property.